# how to create dynamic div in repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am using vb asp.net.

how can i create a new div-row every 3 items? so 3 items will be in one div-row and next 3 item will be in next row

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterGrid" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Picture_Path") %>'/>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: if you put the div with class=row outside the repeater is supposed to work, you have col-4 so every time you completed the 12 columns(add three items in your case) the item go directly to a new line

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, can be achieved by DataList.

```
<asp:DataList ID="MyDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Picture_Path") %>'/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not really working for me. for some reason image, 2 labels are on same line going cross

Comment: Yes.. you are right. You need to locate them. Put in table or div to show as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to wrapping every 3 items inside a single div in a dynamic manner.

1. First, subscribe to repeater's `PreRender` event using the following markup.

   ```
   <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterGrid" runat="server" OnPreRender="repeaterGrid_PreRender">
   ```
2. Then, write VB.Net code inside the above PreRender event to dynamically create a div control and add every 3 repeater items to the dynamically created div control.  You can read the comments which explain every step in detail.

   ```
   Protected Sub repeaterGrid_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   Dim div As HtmlGenericControl = Nothing
   Dim divCounter As Integer = 0
   For Each item As RepeaterItem In repeaterGrid.Items

   'if item is first item in a TRIPLET of repeater items
   'starting from first item having index of 0
       If item.ItemIndex Mod 3 = 0 Then
           div = New HtmlGenericControl("div")

           'below If is not required as its only doing alternating div coloring
           If divCounter Mod 2 = 0 Then
               'even div back color
               div.Style.Add("background-color", "whitesmoke")
           Else
               'odd div back color
               div.Style.Add("background-color", "lightyellow")
           End If

           divCounter = divCounter + 1

           'format is div_{startingItemIndex}_{endingItemIndex}
           div.ID = String.Format("div_{0}_{1}", item.ItemIndex, item.ItemIndex + 2)

           'add repeater item to this newly created div
           div.Controls.Add(item)

          'add this div to the repeater control
           repeaterGrid.Controls.Add(div)
       Else
            'add repeater item to this newly created div
           div.Controls.Add(item)
       End If
   Next

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a few inline ternary operators. Check if the ItemIndex is `0` or `2` with a modulo and create a `<div>` accordingly.
Not that you need one outside the Repeater also if the total items is not dividable by three.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# Container.ItemIndex %3 == 0 ? "<div class=\"col-sm-3\">" : "" %>

        <div><%# Eval("Name") %></div>

        <%# Container.ItemIndex %3 == 2 ? "</div>" : "" %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<%= Repeater1.Items.Count %3 != 0 ? "</div>" : "" %>
```

**VB**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# IIf(Container.ItemIndex Mod 3 = 0, "<div class=""col-sm-3"">", "") %>

        <div>xxx</div>

        <%# IIf(Container.ItemIndex Mod 3 = 2, "</div>", "") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<%= IIf(Repeater1.Items.Count Mod 3 <> 0, "</div>", "") %>
```

Comment: "" character is not valid

Comment: Then you are probably using VB. Added an example.